# Using Boost PRNG to make a huge lookup table of random numbers

Tags: c++, boost, random

I'm trying to use Boost's normal distribution to generate random numbers given different seeds. In other words, I need the same random numbers produced for seed1, seed2, etc.; thousands of seeds will be passed to the function over the course of the simulation. The random number generator will never be used unseeded. **[Edit: "Key" is a better word than "seed"--see final description block below.]** I'm not sure whether it makes the most sense to generate a single RNG and reseed it (and if so, how) or if it's easier to generate a new one each time. Here's what I have so far, which involves the construction of a new, seeded rng at each request for a random normal number:

```
double rnorm( int thisSeed ) {
  boost::mt19937 rng( thisSeed );
  boost::normal_distribution<> nd( 0.0, 1.0 ); // (mean, sd)
  boost::variate_generator > var_nor( rng, nd );
  return var_nor();
}
```

Is this dumb? I'm new to PRNGs and especially Boost's implementation.

---

**A more thorough description of why I'm doing this:**

I am creating a huge random energy landscape to simulate protein interactions: each sequence has a particular energy that's calculated as the sum of quenched Gaussian random numbers that depend on the values of particular amino acids at particular positions (and a few other sequence attributes). I want to use the PRNG to calculate what these pseudorandom values are: these values must be consistent (the same sequence should yield the same values), but there are way too many to store. As a simple example, I might have a sequence ARNDAMR and compute its total energy based on two subenergies: one is a random normal number that depends on having A in position 1 and D at position 4, and the other subenergy is a random number that depends on the last three amino acids. I'm converting the configurations into keys for use as seeds (arguments) for my PRNG. Many thousands of sequences will be constructed and mutated, so I need a way to compute energies quickly--so I need to know how best to seed and call my RNG. I will not be using the Boost RNG for anything other than these energy value "lookups."

---

**Further (tl;dr) explanation:**

I am going to have "key" values that are integers between 1 and 10^6 or 10^7. I want each to map to a Gaussian random number. There should not be any cross-correlation between the key values and their numbers (e.g., keys 145-148 should not map to autocorrelated "random" numbers).

I need a given key to return the same random number each time it (the key) is called in the simulation. I do not want to store the key-random number pairs in a lookup table.

Comment: You generally only seed once, I don't think it makes much sense to have to pass a seed every single time you want a random number. What problem are you solving?

Comment: It might be useful to put this in a separate class, and create different instances of the class with different seeds.

Comment: I agree with @GManNickG. Sarah, you might want to read about the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). If we know *why* you want this, we might be able to help you much better.

Comment: @GManNickG: I'm creating an energy landscape (variant of the NK model) and using the deterministic and pseudorandom properties to "store" the values. Joachim: Could you elaborate?

Comment: I just think it would just be more "object oriented" to abstract this out into a class. Then you can store a list of your PRNG objects in a collection of some kind, and get a number from any of them in any order you want. Might be better than to potentially use magic numbers as seeds to some function you call all over the place.

Comment: I've added a better description of the problem. I'll be looking up the values corresponding to tens of thousands of different seeds, so I'm not sure it's worth storing a list of objects.

Comment: What is the numerical range of your output, and what kind of quantization - minimal difference between output values - is acceptable for your purpose? I ask because if performance is critical to your application, starting with a hash function (a well understood one with a suitable mixing/performance tradeoff, natch) and coercing the hash into your output domain may be a better approach than using a standard PRNG.

Comment: @moonshadow: I really just need these random Gaussian numbers (mean 0, sd = 1). Performance is not critical at this point. There will only be ~10^5 such draws in a standard simulation. I've only used built-in hash functions before, so if you see a huge advantage to using one, please post it as a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach fundmentally misunderstands how PRNGs work. If you reseed on every use, then you won't get random numbers at all, you'll just get a bad hash function of the seed. In particular, your numbers won't be normally distributed even if you're calling the PRNG's normal distribution function, because the PRNG only guarantees that the random numbers generated *from a particular seed* will be normal.

If you need a large set of random numbers to be repeatable for a specific set of inputs, then generate a single number which is a function of those inputs, seed the PRNG with that, then get numbers from the PRNG in a predictable sequence; it will produce the same sequence for the same inputs, and the numbers will be properly distributed by the PRNG.

If the set of inputs you use to determine the random sequence is large (and in particular, larger that the size of the seed for your PRNG), then you won't have a unique sequence for every set of inputs. That might be OK for your application, or you might want to use a PRNG with larger seeds.

Take a look at my public domain [ojrandlib](http://github.com/lcrocker/ojrandlib). It uses big seeds, and generates normally distributed numbers with the fast Ziggurat algorithm.

---

Edit after seeing your clarification:

Ah, now I see. There's no such thing as "a" Gaussian random. Distribution only makes sense with regard to the whole sequence from one seed, so what you need to do is create and seed a single generator, then fetch the Nth random value from that generator for each of your keys N.  If you're not doing this in order (that is, if you're fetching from keys totally at random and not as part of a sequence) this will be very slow, but still possible.  You may want to see if you can force a sequence, say by sorting the keys before you fetch them.

ojrandlib has a function `discard()` for this too, so that if you need to find the 1,000,000th number in a sequence, you can seed the PRNG and discard 999,999 of them, which is faster than actually generating them, but will still be pretty slow.

Probably better: instead of using your key to seed a Gaussian generator, compute a good hash function of the key + fixed seed (which will result in uniformly distributed random bits), then interpret those hash bits as two uniform floats, then do the Box-Muller or Ziggurat with those to transform the distribution. That way, the numbers you get will be all from the same "seed" (which is the input to the hash), but normally distributed. You don't need a cryptographically secure hash, so something like MurMurHash might work well, though you would probably be better off rolling your own for such a special purpose.

---

Thought users of my library might have similar problems to yours, so I investigated some possibilities. Here's some code that might work for you:

```
/* Thomas Wang's 32-bit integer hash */
uint32_t nth_rand32(uint32_t a) {
    a -= a << 6;
    a ^= a >> 17;
    a -= a << 9;
    a ^= a << 4;
    a -= a << 3;
    a ^= a << 10;
    a ^= a >> 15;
    return a;
}

/* Marsaglia polar method */
double nth_normal(int index) {
    double f, g, w;
    int skip = 0;
    uint64_t x, y;

    do {
        x = (uint64_t)nth_rand32((index & ~1) + skip);
        y = (uint64_t)nth_rand32((index | 1) + skip);
        skip += 0x40000001;

        x = (x << 20) | 0x3ff0000000000000ull;
        f = *(double *)(&x) * 2.0 - 3.0;
        y = (y << 20) | 0x3ff0000000000000ull;
        g = *(double *)(&y) * 2.0 - 3.0;

        w = f * f + g * g;
    } while (w >= 1.0 || w == 0.0);

    w = sqrt((-2.0 * log(w)) / w);

    if (index & 1) w *= f;
    else w *= g;
    return w;
}
```

The hash doesn't pass diehard, but it's pretty good. I generated 10,000,000 random normals, and got this distribution (if this image upload works):

[image: Distribution]

Not perfect, but not too bad. It would be a lot better with a more expensive hash, but I'll let you decide where the speed/accuracy tradeoff is for you.

Comment: Lee, thanks for raising this issue. This is something I was worried about but obviously didn't explicitly ask (but should have). I noticed bad bias in the numbers produced and I was planning to investigate. Are you suggesting I take, say, the second number from a RNG with a given seed? This obviously increases computation. I need something that will return random numbers for 3- to 6-digit seeds. I just need one random number per seed.

Comment: No, what I'm saying is that it's meaningless to describe the "distribution" of a single number from any seed. If you need a normal distribution of randoms, you need to seed the generator ONCE, and only ONCE, like any normal use of a PRNG, and call the normal generator function repeatedly on that same generator.  Re-seeding a PRNG is always the wrong thing to do. If you think you need it, you misunderstand the problem.

Comment: Since this PRNG is in >600-dimensional space, I figured it should be enough to take a step a two in from any starting condition, but I can also see how this might be terribly inadequate. So you're proposing that I literally iterate through the sequence of the RNG to some key value (index)? I can't store all the numbers, obviously.

Comment: Store what? If you give a seed to the PRNG, the sequence of numbers it generates will be completely determined from that point on, that's what seeds are for. Why do think you need to store them? You'll have to describe the problem to me in more detail so I can try to understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: Added additional explanation.

Comment: Thanks for the hash suggestions. That is what I need to do; sorting the keys isn't going to save much time with this algorithm. I've been iterating to the nth index for the last half hour and it's (obviously) quite slow. Will read up on hashing. (The "a [blah-distributed] value" is pretty standard shorthand in my field.)